# Windows Azure VM Server 2008 R2 - missing disk space

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We run Windows Azure VM with Server 2008 R2. The system drive c:\ is 126GB in size. All our files & folders on the drive c: together total approx. 33GB so we should be left with approx. 93GB however we have only 34.5GB left. **Why?**

**I've checked for:**
Hidden files
Shadow copy
Rollbacks etc..

but nothing is coming up. I've found an article about the new [TRIM utility](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/releasing-unused-space-from-your-windows-azure-virtual-hard-disk-reduce-billable-size/) for releasing unused drive space but that seems to work only for additional VDs (not the system drives) and this Win 2008 R2 version does not seem to have it included anyway.

Any suggestions ? Thx.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that our MSSQL Server Instance keeps the Error Log Files (not the .LDF) in the LOG folder which for some reason does not inherited the Administrator's permissions/access when the SQL Server instance was installed. There was a

`SQLServerMSSQLUser$Server-Name$MSSQLSERVER(.....`

user access only.

As soon as the administrative access was added for this folder the "missing space" has showed up. It kind of makes sense.

So I guess the lesson to learn here is even though you are a system administrator, do not expect to see everything!

(*~ my thanks to Andy Cao for his help*)